# How do I support an attachable keyboard on ipad when building a touch keypad?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios8

I'm currently developing a touch keypad for iPhone/iPad ( like the one you use to unlock your device ). But I'm having trouble finding documentation on how I can support a 3rd party attachable keyboard for iPad, and make sure it's inputs translate to the touch pad.

Does anyone know what delegates / classes / documentation I can look at to do this?

Thanks,
cpb427

(what I'm talking about )
[image: iphone unlock screen]
<sub>(source: [nirmaltv.com](http://cdn.nirmaltv.com/images/iPhone-6-lockscreen_1.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't dig deep enough before asking this. Apple has a framework for supporting 3rd party devices it's referenced here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference/index.html